# Value from a py file to a kv file. Using the showcase example

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to pass a value from a timer in my main.py to a ProgressBar in a exit.kv file, but using a filestructure like the showcase example. I'm trying to make a timed button, so that the program won't exit by accident, I would need to hold the button down for a few seconds.

Have tried a lot of things but I can't find a solution.

The project need to pass more values read in the main.py (using a DAC on my Raspberry pi) to several different .kv files

This is my first Kivy project but also my first Python project, so the learning curve is steep for me.

---

**EDIT:**

What I need is to pass the value of (*exit_time*) value in the main.py file to the ProgressBar (*exit_bar*) in the exit.kv file to show how long I need to press the button (*exit_button*) before exiting the program.

when the program runs, the python console will do the countdown, but I can't make it show in the ProgressBar (or labels or anything in the exit.kv file.

How do I find if I need to use app. or root. or screen.ids.exit_bar.value or what?

---

**EDIT again: Solution**

I removed everything in the main.py regarding the timer and put this into the main.py;

```
#
#   The Exit Timer, counting up to 20 from 0 before exiting.
#   If Press button start Timer. If button up, reset timer
#

    def my_callback(self, dt):
        global exit_time
        exit_time += 1
        if exit_time == 101:
            sys.exit("piMote stopped!")
        self.time = exit_time

    def start_exit_timer(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 0.01)

    def stop_exit_timer(self):
        global exit_time
        Clock.unschedule(self.my_callback)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.my_callback,0)
        exit_time = -1
```

And then I changed a part of the the exit.ky to

```
   ProgressBar:
        id: exit_bar
        max: 100
        value: app.time
        size_hint_x: .3
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '10dp'
```

In reality all I needed to do was adding *self.time = exit_time"*

---

main.py

```
from time import time
from kivy.app import App
from os.path import dirname, join
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty,\
    ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
import os
import sys
from kivy.config import Config


exit_time = 0
timer_start = 0

class ShowcaseScreen(Screen):
    fullscreen = BooleanProperty(False)
    def add_widget(self, *args):
        if 'content' in self.ids:
            return self.ids.content.add_widget(*args)
        return super(ShowcaseScreen, self).add_widget(*args)

class ShowcaseApp(App):
    index = NumericProperty(-1)
    current_title = StringProperty()
    time = NumericProperty(0)
    screen_names = ListProperty([])
    hierarchy = ListProperty([])
    exit_time = NumericProperty(21)

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'hello world'
        self.screens = {}
        self.available_screens = [
            'Exit']
        self.screen_names = self.available_screens
        curdir = dirname(__file__)
        self.available_screens = [join(curdir, 
            '{}.kv'.format(fn)) for fn in self.available_screens]
        screen = self.load_screen(self.index +1)
        self.current_title = screen.name

#
#   choose the right screen from spinner
#

    def on_current_title(self, instance, value):
        self.root.ids.spnr.text = value

    def go_screen(self, idx):

        print self.index
        self.index = idx
        self.root.ids.sm.switch_to(self.load_screen(idx), direction='left')

    def load_screen(self, index):
        if index in self.screens:
            return self.screens[index]
        screen = Builder.load_file(self.available_screens[index].lower())
        self.screens[index] = screen
        return screen

#
#   timer start for joystick and exit timer
#

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ShowcaseApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_timer, 0.1)

#
#   The Exit Timer, counting up to 20 from 0 before exiting.
#   If Press button start Timer. If button up, reset timer
#

    def my_timer(screen, dt):
        if timer_start == 1:
            global exit_time
            exit_time += 1
            if exit_time == 21:
                sys.exit("piMote stopped!")
            print exit_time
            return exit_time  + 7
        #################################################################
        #   Need to do something here to make the timer-progressbar     #
        #   move, counting how long the button is pressed               #
        #################################################################

    def start_exit_timer(self):
        global timer_start
        timer_start = 1

    def stop_exit_timer(self):
        global timer_start, exit_time
        exit_time = 0
        timer_start = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ShowcaseApp().run()
```

showcase.kv

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<ActionSpinnerOptions@SpinnerOption>
    background_color: .4, .4, .4, 1

<ActionSpinner@Spinner+ActionItem>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.128, 0.128, 0.128, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    border: 27, 20, 12, 12
    #background_normal: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/action_group'
    option_cls: Factory.ActionSpinnerOptions

<ShowcaseScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: False if root.fullscreen else (content.height > root.height - dp(16))
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: root.height if root.fullscreen else max(root.height, content.height)
            GridLayout:
                id: content
                cols: 1
                spacing: '8dp'
                padding: '8dp'
                size_hint: (1, 1) if root.fullscreen else (.8, None)
                height: self.height if root.fullscreen else self.minimum_height

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            #source: 'data/background.png'

    ActionBar:

        ActionView:
            id: av
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'piMote'

            ActionSpinner:
                id: spnr
                important: True
                text: 'Jump to Screen'
                values: app.screen_names
                on_text:
                    if sm.current != args[1]:\
                    idx = app.screen_names.index(args[1]);\
                    app.go_screen(idx)

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        on_current_screen:
            spnr.text = args[1].name
            idx = app.screen_names.index(args[1].name)
            if idx > -1: app.hierarchy.append(idx)
```

exit.kv

```
ShowcaseScreen:
    name: 'Exit'

    Label:
        id: exit_label1
        text: "Are you really sure\n you want to quit?"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '36dp'

    ProgressBar:
        id: exit_bar
        max: 20
        #value: app.my_timer()
        size_hint_x: .3
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '10dp'

    Button:
        id: exit_button
        text: "Yes"
        size_hint_x: .2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: app.start_exit_timer()
        on_release: app.stop_exit_timer()
```

Comment: TL;TR: Can you simplify your example. Post your stacktrace.

Comment: I don't know how to simplify my example and make it work like it should. If I cut anymore from it, it will not work as intended.

Comment: I do not know what a stacktrace is so I can't post it... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a bit too complicated... you can just measure the time that passed since the press and then decide to quit.

```
#forget about all the timers code...
import time #gonna need this
EXIT_BUTTON_TIME = 2.0 # 2 seconds is OK?
...

    def exit_button_pressed(self):
        self.exit_pressed = time.time()


    def exit_button_release(self):
        if time.time() - self.exit_pressed >  EXIT_BUTTON_TIME:
            exit() # or something else you want to do
```

Also change the function names in the KV file...

```
    ...
    on_press: app.exit_button_pressed()
    on_release: app.exit_button_release()
```

I'm not saying that your approach **can't** work, but it is more complex ([import this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

Comment: Thanks, I already have thought about that solution. The "problem" with you solution is not really a problem, but I need to be able to pass other values to an other kv files later on in this project. I'm making a remote controller for my robots, and I need to be able to read the position of the joysticks and display the values in a kv screen.

Comment: @PunyViking - You'll have to write another more concise question about passing parameters around, since the question above is not clear enough.